# Shell script to list unformatted disks (partitions)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk-partitioning

I'm looking to create a script that lists the **unformatted partitions/disks** in Linux OS.

I couldn't find a reliable way of listing the unformatted disks / partitions.

I tried to use `lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT | grep "sd"` which outputted:

```
sda
└─sda1 xfs    /
sdb
└─sdb1 ext4   /mnt/resource
sdc
sdd
```

The names which do not have mountpoint listed against them are unformatted disks. How can I get those names? Or what would be the best way to get these?

I'm on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
lsblk --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F \/ '/sd/ { if ($1 != "" ) dsk=$1;if ( $2 == "") print dsk }'
```

We are storing the partition above the mountpoint line in a variable dsk and then printing it out if there is no mount point i.e. $2 equals null.

Pasting the answer that worked from the comment:

```
lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F \/ '/sd/ { dsk=substr($1,1,3);dsks[dsk]+=1 } END { for ( i in dsks ) { if (dsks[i]==1) print i } }'
```

Comment: `lsblk --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F \/ '/sd/ { if ($1 != "" ) dsk=$1;if ( $2 == "") print dsk }'` 
gives me the following:
`sda
└─sda1
sdb
sdc
sdd`.

I only want the unformatted disks i.e. sdc and sdd:

Comment: OK try: lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F \/ '/sd/ { dsk=substr($1,1,3);dsks[dsk]+=1 } END { for ( i in dsks ) { if (dsks[i]==0) print i } }'

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm. Just had to make a small change. This is what worked: `lsblk -r --output NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk -F \/ '/sd/ { dsk=substr($1,1,3);dsks[dsk]+=1 } END { for ( i in dsks ) { if (dsks[i]==1) print i } }'`

Instead of `if (dsks[i]==0)`, `if (dsks[i]==1)` worked.

Comment: Can you please update your answer so that I can accept it.